# Django elif template tag rendering with constant

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to compare a dictionary value with a constant and I'm noticing these are being treated differently, based on whether I use an if/elif statement and if I just compare the value directly with the value stored in the constant.  Below is an example showing the relevant portions of the context dictionary and the template (only option 2 and 3 work).  Am I missing something here as to why option 1 doesn't work?

view:

```
STATUS1 = 1
STATUS2 = 2
STATUS3 = 3

context = {
    'obj1': {
        'status': STATUS3, 
        'otherattrs': 'other stuff'
    },
    'STATUS1': STATUS1,
    'STATUS2': STATUS2,
    'STATUS3': STATUS3
}
```

option 1 template:

```
{% if obj1.status == STATUS1 %}
    button 1
{% elif obj1.status == STATUS2 %}
    button 2
{% elif obj1.status == STATUS3 %}
    button 3
{% endif %}
```

option 2 template:

```
{% if obj1.status == STATUS1 %}
    button 1
{% endif %}
{% if obj1.status == STATUS2 %}
    button 2
{% endif %}
{% if obj1.status == STATUS3 %}
    button 3
{% endif %}
```

option 3 template:

```
{% if obj1.status == 1 %}
    button 1
{% elif obj1.status == 2 %}
    button 2
{% elif obj1.status == 3 %}
    button 3
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce your issue, all three approaches output `button 3` for me. What result are you seeing for option one?